# Webgl/JS how to zoom in on a fractal

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, zooming, fragment-shader

I have a mandelbrot fractal and im trying to zoom in, but I dont know how. What am I suppose to do? This is how the fractal is drawn.

```
vec4 mandelbrot (vec2 coord){
    vec2 z0 = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
    int number = fractal (z0, coord);
    if (number == -1)
        return vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);   
    float v = float(number);
    //float factor = -1.0;
    return (paletize (v, factor));
}
```

Comment: You could find examples with zooming fractals at [Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/).